# Setting property of objects in array

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an array of objects:

```
[{
   id: 1,
   cod: '123',
   val: true      
},
{
   id: 2,
   cod: '123',
   val: true      
},
{
   id: 3,
   cod: '123',
   val: true      
},
{
   id: 4,
   cod: '456',
   val: true      
},
{
   id: 5,
   cod: '456',
   val: true      
}]
```

I need to maintain the `val` property `true` for the objects which have the same `cod` and have the higher id. For example, I'd need the following output:

```
[{
   id: 1,
   cod: '123',
   val: false
},
{
   id: 2,
   cod: '123',
   val: false
},
{
   id: 3,
   cod: '123',
   val: true      
},
{
   id: 4,
   cod: '456',
   val: false
},
{
   id: 5,
   cod: '456',
   val: true      
}]
```

How could I change this array in order to obtain the desired results? Should I use filter? I'm a little lost.

Comment: *"Should I use filter?"* Probably not. Is the array always going to be sorted by ID?

Comment: Yes, it will always be sorted by ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to process and mutate every element in the array (assuming in-place mutation is fine), so `.filter` is not suitable here, since it usually just "removes" elements.

A general approach would be: Iterate over every element of the array and keep a `cod => previous item` map to keep track of the previous item with the same `cod` value. Set `val` of the current item to `true`, set `val` of the previous item with the same `cod` value to `false`, update tracking entry for current item's `cod` value.

Example:

```js
const data = [{
   id: 1,
   cod: '123',
   val: true      
},
{
   id: 2,
   cod: '123',
   val: true      
},
{
   id: 3,
   cod: '123',
   val: true      
},
{
   id: 4,
   cod: '456',
   val: true      
},
{
   id: 5,
   cod: '456',
   val: true      
}];

const previousCod = new Map();

for (const item of data) {
  if (previousCod.has(item.cod)) {
    previousCod.get(item.cod).val = false;
  }
  // Can be omitted if the initial value is guaranteed to be `true`
  item.val = true;
  previousCod.set(item.cod, item);
}

console.log(data);
```